# Make Select box required in Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drupal

I have created a field **"Cars"** of type List(text) in Drupal 8 which has these values

```
                        0|Lambo
                        1|MER
                        2|BMW
                        3|Aston
                        4|Range Rover
                        5|Limo
```

I have selected **"- None -"** as default value and i have not made this field required by clicking checkbox in drupal edit settings, i want to make this field required through JQuery.

I have tried Jquery code:-

```
        jQuery('#edit-field-secondary-waste-type').prop('required', true);
```

Expected result is that the field gets required but actually it is not working and form is saving with **"None"** value as it was set as default value.

Comment: Any particular reason to use jQuery required instead of default Drupal required selected via UI?

Comment: Yes, Because his field is secondary. Is hidden by default, under some particular condition it becomes visible, so i can't make it required with drupal UI.

Comment: Ok this sounds like it can be handled with [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). If you need more custom solution it can be done with [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.6.x) and form [states](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states).

I am guessing that with jQuery approach "None" is still a value (it is not like user did not pick anything) and because of it form is passed and field saves default value. 

For more detailed answer I should have more info.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely on same page with me. The text fields can be made required with jquery approach, but the file and select fields need to be validated in "form validation" function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :-

**Important Note-**  We are not using Drupal8's in built required checkbox field in field settings because here we are discussing about secondary form, which is hidden by default and shows up under some condition.

So,

In Drupal8, Text fields can be made required using JQuery approach, but the "select" fields and "upload file" do not get along with jQuery.

**Here is one of the solution :-**

You can make them check for validation in your "Validate" function

Here is my Code :-

**in code field names to be placed with your field names i have used random values for example**

```
public static function node_content_type_xyz_form_validate(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){



   $primary =  $form_state->getValue('field_name')[0]['value'];

   $reset_text_fields=[];

//in my case this was the condition**

   if($primary < 4){
      $form_state->setValue('field_secondary_waste_type',$reset_text_fields);
            }



    // here is the validation**



      else{

        $empty=[];
        $value_of_secondary_waste_type = $form_state->getValue('field_secondary_waste_type')[0]['value'];

        if($value_of_secondary_waste_type == null){

          $form_state->setErrorByName('field_secondary_waste_type', t('Secondary Waste Type is required.'));

        }


        if(($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 1) || ($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 2) || ($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 3 ) || ($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 5)){

          $value_of_pcpg = $form_state->getValue('field_secondary_pcpg_facility_ty')[0]['value'];

            if($value_of_pcpg == null) {
               $form_state->setErrorByName('field_secondary_pcpg_facility_ty', t('Secondary Facility Type is required.'));
            }



        }

        if($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 0){

            $value_of_residual = $form_state->getValue('field_secondary_residual_facilit')[0]['value'];

            if($value_of_residual == null ){
               $form_state->setErrorByName('field_secondary_residual_facilit', t('Secondary Facility Type is required.'));
            }

        }

        if($value_of_secondary_waste_type == 4){
          $metal = $form_state->getValue('field_secondary_metal_facility_t')[0]['value'];

          if($metal == null){
            $form_state->setErrorByName('field_secondary_metal_facility_t', t('Secondary Facility Type is required.'));
          }


        }


        $variable= $form_state->getValue('field_secondary_permit_pdf')[0]['fids'];
        if($value_of_secondary_upload_permit == $empty){
          $form_state->setErrorByName('field_xyz', t('Secondary Permit PDF is required.'));
        }

   }



  }
```

Thanks
Kushal Agrawal
kushalagrawal.1996@gmail.com